# Deploying Laravel to Azure - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have managed to deploy my laravel application to Azure using Bitbucket. Since i am unable to run composer install on Azure Devops, I git commit the vendor folder to the bitbcuket for deployment.

I understand the best practice is to ignore the vendor folder and run composer install on the server to install all dependencies.

Is there a way i can run composer install on Azure Devops pipeline so i could gitignore the vendor folder during my git push ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to install composer inside your project folder, you should provide read and write access. Following method will help you to install composer

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME`

`sudo composer install`